# Как добавить событие в тело Placemark (Маркера) в yandex картах (React)

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Не пойму как добавить собитие в Placemark, точнее в его тело BalloonContentBody

```
export const MapEtm = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const changeStore = ()=>{
    alert('555')
  }

  return (
    <YMaps>
      <Map width="100%"
           height="100%"
           defaultState={ {
             center: props.stores[0].gps.split(','),
             zoom: 5,
             controls: [ 'zoomControl' ],
           } }
           modules={ [ 'control.ZoomControl' ] }
      >
        <Clusterer
          options={ {
            preset: 'islands#blueCircleIcon',
            groupByCoordinates: false,
          } }
          // props.changeCurrentStore
        >
          { props.stores.map((coordinates, index) => (
            <Placemark key={ index } modules={ [ 'geoObject.addon.balloon' ] } changeStore={changeStore} geometry={ coordinates.gps.split(',') }
                       properties={ {
                         balloonContentBody:
                         `
                        <div  style='max-width:200px; padding:10px; display:flex; flex-direction: column;'>
                           <div style='margin-bottom:5px; color:#2b2b2b; font-weight: bold;'>${ coordinates.metro?coordinates.metro:'' }</div>
                           <div style='margin-bottom:5px;color:#6f6f6f; font-weight:500'>${ coordinates.name }</div>
                           <div style='color:#1181d7;font-weight:500'>${ coordinates.time }</div>
                           <button onClick={'ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ СОБЫТИЕ'} style='margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;color:#fff; background:#1181d7; outline: none; border:none; width:150px; cursor:pointer; padding:7px 10px; text-transform:uppercase; border-radius: 2px;' >Выбрать</button>
                           <div style='color:#034ea2; font-size:18px; font-weight: 400;'>${ coordinates.phone }</div>
                          
                         </div>
                         
                         `

                         ,
                       } }
            />
          )) }
        </Clusterer>
      </Map>
    </YMaps>
  )
}
```

Событие должно вешаться в proterties -> balloonContentBody -> Кнопка button.
Событие прилетает в эту компонету пропсами. Пробовал вариант onClick={()=> props.someEvents()} - и прочие вариации не работают

После выполнения onClick должно еще срабатывать событие закрытия тела маркера (это отдельный вопрос).
За помощь заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

нашел решение для себя.
Функцию можно поместить в объект window

```
 window.setWarehouse = function (point) {
    props.changeCurrentStore(''+ point) - это моя функция
    let close = document.querySelector('ymaps[class$="-balloon__close-button"]');  - событие которое закрое тело placemark после выполнения моей функции
    if (close != null) {
      close.click()
    }
  }
```

и в теле placemark на кнопку вешаем эту функцию

```
<button onclick="window.setWarehouse(${ coordinates.code });">Выбрать</button>
```

Решение не элегантно, но работает. Если есть более лучший код, то буду рад.